# adding RBAC role for a Managed identity on multiple resource groups via automation

Tags: azure, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity

Is there a way to add RBAC role for a usr based managed identity on multiple resource groups via automation (CLI, PowerShell, Terraform etc). It would save me time of manually adding the permissions on on multiple resource groups.

I started with this, which gets me an object ID of the Managed identity.
az resource list -g "RG Name" --query "[?identity!=null].{name: name, objectIds: identity.principalId}"

Thanks!

Comment: you could use `az role assignment` (CLI) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: you could use `New-AzRoleAssignment` (Az Powershell) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-8.1.0

Comment: you could use `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments` (Bicep / ARM) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scenarios-rbac

Answer (score 1):

> RBAC role for a usr based managed identity on multiple resource groups
> via automation (CLI, PowerShell, Terraform etc).

- *Here are the codes for RBAC rules for different services Terraform CLI and PowerShell.*

*[CLI:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest)*

```
az role assignment create --role
                          [--assignee]
                          [--assignee-object-id]
                          [--assignee-principal-type {ForeignGroup, Group, ServicePrincipal, User}]
                          [--condition]
                          [--condition-version]
                          [--description]
                          [--resource-group]
                          [--scope]
```

*[PowerShell:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest)*

```
New-AzRoleAssignment
   -ObjectId <String>
   [-Scope <String>]
   -RoleDefinitionName <String>
   [-Description <String>]
   [-Condition <String>]
   [-ConditionVersion <String>]
   [-ObjectType <String>]
   [-AllowDelegation]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

*[Terraform:](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment)*

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_definition" "example" {
  role_definition_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  name               = "my-custom-role-definition"
  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id

  permissions {
    actions     = ["Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read"]
    not_actions = []
  }

  assignable_scopes = [
    data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  name               = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_id = azurerm_role_definition.example.role_definition_resource_id
  principal_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.example.object_id
}
```